# Spring webflux ReactiveMongoOperations find by elemMatch

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I have a collection like this:

```
{"type": "bbb", "category": "aaa", "from": "eee", "INTERLOCUTOR": ["test1", "test2"]}
```

and I want to find **INTERLOCUTOR** have ***test1*** ;
how to use by **ReactiveMongoOperations**?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.find({"INTERLOCUTOR" : "test1"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReactiveMongoOperations` and processing the returned `reactor.core.publisher.Flux` to print the query returned documents:

```
ReactiveMongoOperations ops = new ReactiveMongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Criteria c = Criteria.where("INTERLOCUTOR").is("test1");
Query qry = new Query(c);

Flux<Document> flux = ops.find(qry, Document.class, "coll")
flux.subscribe(doc -> System.out.println(doc), throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace());
```

Note the query actually executes when the `subscribe` method runs. Since the subscribe runs as an asynchronous operation, when you run this add the following to the current thread (for blocking it until the async operation completes).

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch(InterruptedException e ) {}
```

Comment: @prased_ it might be a silly question but I really want to understand it: if I have to block for 1 second until the async subscribe complete what is the advantage to use ReactiveMongoOperations?

Comment: @JimC Actual applications don't run 5 lines of code in the `main` method and end the application after querying a database's collection. There is more to an application - this is just to demonstrate the basic usage of the API and its syntax. The `Flux` (and also see `Mono`) class has methods to work with various scenarios (including blocking methods) and you can use the ones that are suitable for your application.