# how save document to MongoDb with com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client

Tags: java, mongodb, java-stream, reactive-programming, reactive-streams

I am trying to insert a document in MongoDb throw reactive driver: com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client

According to [official guide](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver-reactive/getting-started/quick-start/) "... Only when a Publisher is subscribed to and data requested will the operation happen... Once the document has been inserted the onNext method will be called " and provided an example which I tried bellow without success. By debugging I see that onSubscribe is called but onNext bellow is never called and I checked in MongoDb the document isn't inserted also.

Here is what I have tried

```
import com.mongodb.client.result.InsertOneResult;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase;


import java.util.Arrays;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mycollection");

        Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
                .append("type", "database")
                .append("count", 1)
                .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));


        Publisher<InsertOneResult> publisher = collection.insertOne(doc);

        publisher.subscribe(new Subscriber<InsertOneResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
                s.request(1);  // <--- Data requested and the insertion will now occur
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final InsertOneResult result) {
                System.out.println("Inserted: " + result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-mongoreactive-mvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Am I missing some point while subscribing?

*** edited after Prasad_'s suggestion

Here is the final solution. Weird to me that all examples of reading/querying from [official guide](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver-reactive/getting-started/quick-start/) drove me to use an example provided from 6 years ago.

```
import com.mongodb.client.result.InsertOneResult;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;



public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        //MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://root:q@localhost:27017");
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mycollection");

        Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
                .append("type", "database")
                .append("count", 1)
                .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));


        Publisher<InsertOneResult> publisher = collection.insertOne(doc);

        publisher.subscribe(new Subscriber<InsertOneResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
                s.request(1);  // <--- Data requested and the insertion will now occur
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final InsertOneResult result) {
                System.out.println("Inserted: " + result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }
        });

        //I am wondering if I am in right direction because I have just copied SubscriberHelpers to my project in order to countDocuments and find
        collection.countDocuments()
                .subscribe(new SubscriberHelpers.PrintSubscriber<Long>("total # of documents after inserting "
                        + " is: %s"));

        collection.find(eq("name", "MongoDB")).first().subscribe(new SubscriberHelpers.PrintDocumentSubscriber());

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

}
```

and in order to count documents I added also (just copied from [an example from 6 years ago](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/tree/master/examples/tour/src/main/tour)

```
import com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static java.lang.String.format;

/**
 *  Subscriber helper implementations for the Quick Tour.
 */
public final class SubscriberHelpers {

    /**
     * A Subscriber that stores the publishers results and provides a latch so can block on completion.
     *
     * @param <T> The publishers result type
     */
    public static class ObservableSubscriber<T> implements Subscriber<T> {
        private final List<T> received;
        private final List<Throwable> errors;
        private final CountDownLatch latch;
        private volatile Subscription subscription;
        private volatile boolean completed;

        ObservableSubscriber() {
            this.received = new ArrayList<T>();
            this.errors = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
            this.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
            subscription = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final T t) {
            received.add(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable t) {
            errors.add(t);
            onComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            completed = true;
            latch.countDown();
        }

        public Subscription getSubscription() {
            return subscription;
        }

        public List<T> getReceived() {
            return received;
        }

        public Throwable getError() {
            if (errors.size() > 0) {
                return errors.get(0);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isCompleted() {
            return completed;
        }

        public List<T> get(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws Throwable {
            return await(timeout, unit).getReceived();
        }

        public ObservableSubscriber<T> await() throws Throwable {
            return await(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

        public ObservableSubscriber<T> await(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws Throwable {
            subscription.request(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            if (!latch.await(timeout, unit)) {
                throw new MongoTimeoutException("Publisher onComplete timed out");
            }
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                throw errors.get(0);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A Subscriber that immediately requests Integer.MAX_VALUE onSubscribe
     *
     * @param <T> The publishers result type
     */
    public static class OperationSubscriber<T> extends ObservableSubscriber<T> {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
            super.onSubscribe(s);
            s.request(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A Subscriber that prints a message including the received items on completion
     *
     * @param <T> The publishers result type
     */
    public static class PrintSubscriber<T> extends OperationSubscriber<T> {
        private final String message;

        /**
         * A Subscriber that outputs a message onComplete.
         *
         * @param message the message to output onComplete
         */
        public PrintSubscriber(final String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println(format(message, getReceived()));
            super.onComplete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A Subscriber that prints the json version of each document
     */
    public static class PrintDocumentSubscriber extends OperationSubscriber<Document> {

        @Override
        public void onNext(final Document document) {
            super.onNext(document);
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
    }

    private SubscriberHelpers() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is just fine. What is happening is that the `publisher#subscribe` is an asynchronous operation. The `main` method in which the code is running is exiting before the asynchronous call is completed. So, just add `Thread.sleep(1000);` after the `publisher#subscribe` method, and you will see the insertion works as expected. See similar explanation in [Spring webflux ReactiveMongoOperations find by elemMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206481/spring-webflux-reactivemongooperations-find-by-elemmatch/64207864#64207864).

Comment: Thanks, now I see the document inserted. A question if you don't mind: all examples of reading/retrieving data from MongoDb throw reactivestreams are using a class named SubscriberHelpers from an example named Tour (I added above). have you worked with MongoDb Reactive? Have you also copied and pasted such SubscriberHelpers class coded 6 years ago? Would you suggest other approach? PS. please post as answer so I can pick it up

Comment: Actually, in real applications you should be using an implementation of [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/), like [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). Project Reactor of Spring Framework is another option.

Comment: @prasad_, my final goal is to code a reactive application based on Micronaut instead of Spring. Since I saw Micronaut can add support for the Mongo Reactive Streams Driver I started study it and the above code is a simplified application to help me ask about com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client. Suppose you have to code a reactive application with Kafka and any nosql database and you can't add Spring dependencies: which one would you chose as reactive driver for database? I see micronaut can add vertx-mysql-client
support for Reactive MySQL Client. Would you suggest vertx as reactive db driver?

Comment: My suggestion to use `Thread.sleep(1000);` was before you coded `SubscriberHelpers` utility provided with the examples. I have explained the reason, why you need the Thread.sleep. You probably, require only one of the two, not both.